# Python openCv calcHist failing with error code (-215)

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Hi I'm getting this error when I run my code:

Assertion failed `(mask.size() == imsize && mask.channels() == 1) in          histPrepareImages, file /Users/jmeunier28/Downloads/opencv-    3.0.0/modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp, line 159`

`File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyimagesearch/rgbhistogram.py", line 16, in describe
    mask, self.bins, [0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])`

In `pyimagesearch/rgbhistogram.py` I am trying to use calcHist like so:

```
def describe(self, image, mask = None):

        hist = cv2.calcHist([image], [0, 1, 2],
        mask, self.bins, [0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])

    hist = cv2.normalize(hist,hist)

    # return out 3D histogram as a flattened array
    return hist.flatten()
```

Then in my main script i run this:

```
desc = RGBHistogram([8, 8, 8])

for (imagePath, maskPath) in zip(imagePaths, masksPaths):
    # load the images in the path
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    mask = cv2.imread(maskPath,0) 
    features = desc.describe(image,mask)
    data.append(features)
    target.append(imagePath.split("_")[-2])
```

The images are of shape (142,213,3) and the shape of the masks are (142,213) is this the source of the problem? I am new to python and I uninstalled numpy and opencv and reinstalled them and this did not correct it. I cannot think of any other reason why this would not work correctly. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it!

**EDIT:**
The images are photos of different animals and I have written a script that creates the mask images of the animals here:

```
for i in range(imgnum):
    im = cv2.imread(imagePaths[i],0)
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(im,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    target = imagePaths[i].split("_")[-2]
    newImg= cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(dirname,target+"_"+str(i)+".jpg"),thresh)
```

Comment: It seems it expects black'n'white image as input.

Comment: Shouldn't you call `image = cv2.imread(imagePath)` with second parameter as `0` also?

Comment: baldr I tried this and i gives me this error now: `Assertion failed (j < nimages) in histPrepareImages, file /Users/jmeunier28/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp, line 146`

Comment: Did you try printing out `image.dtype` and `mask.dtype` to make sure the types are correct (mask should be 8-bit)? That's not the condition in the assert, so I'm just pulling at straws.

Comment: Kmac, yes I did do that and mask is dtype= uinut8 and so is image